# Error updating values in apache parquet file with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I don't know if this is the best practice for updating data, I have a parquet file partitioned by date in S3, and I have a daily job that appends data to this parquet file but sometimes is needed to run the job again and persist the data.

This is the code for saving the data to the parquet file

```
if( (df_max_date.compareTo(max_date)) > 0 ){
  //Append new data
  println("append mode ...")
     df
      .write.mode("append")
      .partitionBy("date")
      .parquet(s"s3n://...")


}else{

  val new_df = df
  .filter($"date" !== max_date)
  .unionAll(new_df)

  println("overwrite mode ...")
  new_df
    .write.mode("overwrite")
    .partitionBy("date")
    .parquet(s"s3n://...")
}
```

The append part works ok but in the overwrite part sometimes I get this error:

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:334)
```

Comment: The excerpt you pasted is just the call stack, the exception itself is missing from the top of it. Could you include the previous line of the error output in your question?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, at this point the error is not important I made a workaround persisting a temporary file after that I do the union and then the overwrite, I don't know if there is a better solution.